# How to install a blog into an existing website?

Tags: blogs

I have an existing website and I would like to install blog with the same header and footer layout.

Is it possible to place a blog in the middle/body of the page, incorporate into an existing web page?

Or do I have to build it from scratch?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Many thanks.

Comment: more infos, please. What type of website? Basically, it's easy to install a wordpress into a subdir of the website. It's possible, too, to change the wordpress template so that it looks like your "old" webpage.

Comment: Is your website just a bunge of static pages?

Comment: Isn't this question more suitable for serverfault or superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your most common options are [Blogger](http://blogger.com/home) and [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/).

Generally you'll setup the blog in a different URL like www.mysite.com/blog. Each blogging service has its own manual that teaches you how to configure the blog according to your needs.

You can of course configure the blog to have the look and feel of your main site. To do that you have to configure some files (probably CSS stylesheet files).

Follow these useful tutorials...

Blogger:

[How to Publish a Blogger Blog to a Website](http://www.ehow.com/how_2065365_publish-blogger-blog-website.html)

Wordpress:

[Installing WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)

[Tutorial: How to Integrate Wordpress into an Existing Website](http://jonathanwold.com/tutorials/wordpress_integration/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a specific technology ?

If you use Rails, Sinatra or any other Ruby/Rack based framework, I can recommend [toto](http://cloudhead.io/toto) for that exact purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is not very big and quite static, you could try to accomplish the *opposite* thing: build your site into a blog.

Take a look at Wordpress for example